# Unable to update to xcode6

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

I had xcode 5.1.1 running on my Mac air. When I tried to update it to Xcode 6, it threw an error "This item is temporarily unavailable. Try again later." I have tried uninstalling the older version, restarting and then installing the new version. Nothing has worked so far.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Only Xcode won't download. Everything else updates/downloads correctly.

Comment: no problem here, click on instal in apple store and it works for me.

Comment: I got this fixed. On the Dashboard there was a "paused" icon for xcode. Deleted it,restarted and installed xcode6. Worked fine.

Comment: In Dashboard or LaunchPad and how did you delete it?